# Boot in rescue mode with vlan support in RHEL

Tags: rhel, vlan, rescue

I am trying to restore **RHEL** OS (5.3.1.1) from network, where we have VLANs configured on our switches.
So the only way to get to shared folder on remote server with backup image is to configure VLAN.

I booted a machine with Red Hat Recovery CD and ran `linux rescue`. But in this mode there is no VLAN support. No file under `/proc/net/vlan/config` and there is no module loaded (`lsmod|grep 802` gives nothing).

Is there a way to boot from CD/DVD with 8021q support? `modprobe 8021q` in a regular `linux rescue` mode gives error due to missing folders with `modules.dep`.
On official web site I found some info that we can add more keys after `linux rescue` command in order to include support of other things.

Does anybody knows how to make `linux rescue` boot with VLAN support (8021q)?

Comment: So your vlan is not port based, but tagged one? Anyway you are not booting from network but from cdrom/iso. What about PXE and customer kernel with vlan module and initramfs?

Answer (score 1):

You could boot a CentOS live-cd instead.

Another idea (I did not try that) would be to boot from a different distribution`s rescue-cd (OpenSuSE?)

Comment: The problem is that I have specific HW with RAID and scripts that I have to use for restore. I cannot user other images.

Comment: If that specific hardware works with RH 5 in rescue mode it will surely work with newer - other - linux distributions (Try CentOS 6.2). And your scripts are shell-scripts? Should work everywhere.